# Print Sum of Particular Columns from a CSV file WITHOUT using PANDA

Tags: python, csv, sum, etl, multiple-columns

I have a CSV file named PC_Sales.csv with five headers and which looks like the following. I have to build a Datawarehouse based on this data.

```
Country       Year         Time_Quarter         Manufacturer      Sales
Brazil        2010             1                    Acer            60
Brazil        2010             1                     HP             70
Brazil        2010             2                    Acer            50
Brazil        2010             2                     HP             50
Brazil        2011             1                    Acer            50
Brazil        2011             1                     HP             40
Brazil        2011             2                    Acer            20
Brazil        2011             2                     HP             30
France        2010             1                    Acer            90
France        2010             1                     HP             20
France        2010             2                    Acer            80
France        2010             2                     HP             50
France        2011             1                    Acer            60
France        2011             1                     HP             30
France        2011             2                    Acer            30
France        2011             2                     HP             40
```

The program will ask for input from the user between 1-3.
If the user selects input = 1, the output will be the countries with the total sum of the Sales like the following:
If input = 1, output will be:

```
Country   Sales
Brazil     370
France     400
```

If the input = 2, the output will be the total number of sales by manufacturer of each countries:

```
Country         Manufacturer        Sales
Brazil              Acer             180
                     HP              190
France              Acer             260
                     HP              140
```

If the input = 3, it will print with the total sales numbers (of both the countries) with Time Quarter and Time Year and Manufacturer:

```
Quarter          Year         Manufacturer       Sales
1                2010             Acer            150 (60+90,60=Brazil Q1, 90=France Q1)
1                2010              HP              90
2                2010             Acer            130
2                2010              HP             100
1                2011             Acer            110
1                2011              HP              70
2                2011             Acer             50
2                2011              HP              70
```

The code needs to be done without using Panda. Itertools() can be used in this case if required!

Comment: Just wanted to know the reason, why you don't want to use pandas?

Comment: Why do you suggest using itertools? I’ve written tons of CSV-processing code in Python and never touched itertools.

Comment: It’s okay if it can be done without using itertools, but I want to do it without using Pandas!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is the following.

Here we create a suitable data structure for this task. In your case, you must read it from a `csv` file.

```py
import re

raw = """Country       Year         Time_Quarter         Manufacturer      Sales
Brazil        2010             1                    Acer            60
Brazil        2010             1                     HP             70
Brazil        2010             2                    Acer            50
Brazil        2010             2                     HP             50
Brazil        2011             1                    Acer            50
Brazil        2011             1                     HP             40
Brazil        2011             2                    Acer            20
Brazil        2011             2                     HP             30
France        2010             1                    Acer            90
France        2010             1                     HP             20
France        2010             2                    Acer            80
France        2010             2                     HP             50
France        2011             1                    Acer            60
France        2011             1                     HP             30
France        2011             2                    Acer            30
France        2011             2                     HP             40
"""

header, *rows = raw.strip().split("\n")

columns = re.sub("\s+", ",", header).split(",")
data = [dict(zip(columns,re.sub("\s+", ",", row).split(","))) for row in rows]
```

Then it is possible to use the following snippet to count the items (`input = 1`)

```py
x = "Sales"
to_be_aggregated = ("Country", )
results = {k: 0 for k in set([tuple(itm[tba] for tba in to_be_aggregated) for itm in data])}

for itm in data:
    for key in results.keys():
        if all(itm[tba] == k for tba, k in zip(to_be_aggregated, key)):
            results[key] += int(itm[x])
```

The output is:

```
{('France',): 400, ('Brazil',): 370}
```

Using the same logic it is possible to count items when `input = 2` setting `to_be_aggregated = ("Country", "Manufacturer")`, then the output is

```
{('Brazil', 'HP'): 190,
 ('Brazil', 'Acer'): 180,
 ('France', 'HP'): 140,
 ('France', 'Acer'): 260}
```

In the same vein you can manage `input = 3` setting `to_be_aggregated = ("Country", "Manufacturer", "Year", "Time_Quarter")`.

As a sanity check, you can perform the same aggregation using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[x] = df[x].astype(int)

agg = df.groupby(by=list(to_be_aggregated)).sum()

for key, val in results.items():
    assert agg.loc[key].iat[0] == val
```